# Is a function a constructor if it uses convert (Julia)?

Tags: constructor, type-conversion, julia

Reading the source code of BioSeq.jl I found that they use functions like this:

```
aminoacid{T<:Number}(value::T) = convert(AminoAcid, value)
```

This functions creates a new object of the type `AminoAcid` by performing a conversion. Is this function considered a contructor (and therefore should be named `AminoAcid` instead of `aminoacid`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally, yes, that `aminoacid` method is doing the work of a constructor.  This is especially true in light of the call-overload improvements in 0.4-dev, where all types have a very similar [default constructor fallback to `convert`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/ff9cebe45e6c39933ab26ca134b59b3ef47ec821/base/base.jl#L36).

It seems like the Julian style is moving away from these lowercase constructor functions, especially when they're just doing conversion. See for example [Issue #9155: in 0.4, is `Symbol("foobar")` canonical?](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/9155).

Here is a nice rule of thumb for when to use lowercase methods ([Comment by Steven G. Johnson on Interact.jl#17: lower case widget functions](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Interact.jl/issues/17#issuecomment-53085494)):

> The lower-case versions, like `int(...)`, are things that are (a) more coercive in conversions (no InexactErrors) and (b) may not return the corresponding type. e.g. `int([1.0, 3.7])` works and returns an array of integers. See also [JuliaLang/julia#1470](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1470).